# Is WebView not supported in a MUXC:Navigation

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winui-3

so I am needing to have to pages have webviews in my UWP application. I have them set in the muxc:NavigationViewItem when I navigate to them I am able to see the web page load in but when I got to interact with the page I am unable to do anything at all. I have switched it back to the normal NavigationViewItem and onve I do that I have no issues with interacting with the page inside the webview. Is the Webview not supported in a muxc:NavigationView? Any help on this issue would mean the world, thanks!

**Here is the code that interacting with a webpage inside Webview doesn't work**

```
        <muxc:NavigationView OpenPaneLength="175" 
                         x:Name="NavView" 
                         ItemInvoked="NavView_ItemInvoked" 
                         Loaded="NavView_Loaded" 
                         IsSettingsVisible="True"
                         IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed">
        <muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="Home" Content="Home" Tag="Home" />
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Content="Create New Report" Tag="CreateNewReport" >
                <muxc:NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="./Assets/TestIcon.png" />
                </muxc:NavigationViewItem.Icon>
            </muxc:NavigationViewItem>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="Bookmarks" Content="Daily Log" Tag="DailyLog" />
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="Keyboard" Content="CAD" Tag="CAD" />
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="Calculator" Content="MULES" Tag="MULES" />
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="World" Content="MARS Workflow" Tag="MARSWorkflow" />
            <!--<NavigationViewItem Icon="Find" Content="MARS Search" Tag="MARSSearch" />-->
        </muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <ScrollViewer >
                <Frame Name="ContentFrame" />
            </ScrollViewer>



    </muxc:NavigationView>
```

**Code that allows for interaction inside a Webview**

```
<NavigationView OpenPaneLength="175" 
                         x:Name="NavView" 
                         ItemInvoked="NavView_ItemInvoked" 
                         Loaded="NavView_Loaded" 
                         IsSettingsVisible="True"
                         IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Home" Content="Home" Tag="Home" />
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Create New Report" Tag="CreateNewReport" >
                <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="./Assets/TestIcon.png" />
                </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
            </NavigationViewItem>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Bookmarks" Content="Daily Log" Tag="DailyLog" />
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Keyboard" Content="CAD" Tag="CAD" />
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Calculator" Content="MULES" Tag="MULES" />
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="World" Content="MARS Workflow" Tag="MARSWorkflow" />
            <!--<NavigationViewItem Icon="Find" Content="MARS Search" Tag="MARSSearch" />-->
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <ScrollViewer >
                <Frame Name="ContentFrame" />
            </ScrollViewer>



    </NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce this on my side. This is a known issue that has been reported on WinUI Github issues-[Unable to Interact with WebView in WinUI 2.6](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/5299).

The reason for this behavior is that the rounding of the navigation view content area makes it unable to interact. So as a workaround, please try to set `NavigationViewContentGridCornerRadius` to 0. After that, the code works on my side.

Please put the following code into the Page where you place the **muxc:NavigationView** .

```
  <Page.Resources>
    <CornerRadius x:Key="NavigationViewContentGridCornerRadius">0</CornerRadius>
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks so much that took care of my issue!

Comment: @Pierce_Kennnedy437 Does my workaround help you fix the issue?

Comment: Yes! That got my issue you fixed, thanks so much!